# CRC calculation stuck

Tags: networking, error-handling, crc

I have a polynom CRC that I can't solve.

x^5 + x^2 + 1

data: 1011100110001

I did like this:

```
100101 | 1011100110001
         100101
         -------
         0010110
          000000
          ------
           101101
           100101
           ------
            010001
            000000
            ------
             100010   
             000000    <- I wrote here 0's because 100101 > 100010
             ------
             1000100
              100101
             -------
             1100001    <- Here is the problem! It's more than 5 bits.
```

What's wrong with my calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your "000000" lines, but how about this:

```
Input data: 1011100110001
Polynom: 100101 (n = 6)

101110011000100000 <- expand input data by n-1 zeros
100101             <- polynom aligned to most left 1 of input data
--------
00101101           <- input XOR polynom, then get next input bit 
  100101            
  ------            
  00100010         <- and so on...
    100101
    -------
    000111001
       100101 
       ------
       0111000
        100101
        ------
        0111010
         100101
         ------
         0111110
          100101
          -------
          0110110
           100101
           ------
           0100110
            100101 <- ... until all input bits are "used up"
            ------
            000011 <- CRC result
```

Comment: Why you did the row of "and so on"? I see you added multiple numbers from the data where the number is not enough for the XOR but I thought that allways where the result is smaller then the divider we add numbers